# what type of design diagram for a multiple thread based application?

Tags: .net, multithreading, uml, diagramming

What type of design diagram is recommended for capturing the high level/concept design of an application that has multiple threads?   Any examples?

In my specific case (C# WPF app) I have a application that has:

- a UI project & some class libraries (util classes broken out for reuse)
- classes within (both UI and class library)
- but also about 5 different threads (including UI thread) handling various things

Comment: Sequence diagram is usually a good one if you are trying to describe what happens when, a sequence diagram can be sort of drawn to be some amalgamation of time-based execution (whereas usually it just describes the sequence of events without time). I've added this as a comment because it's not a very good answer, I'm curious to see if there is an "official" diagram available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687) book, which is a summary of the [Booch/Rumbaugh/Jacobson book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321267974), says to use UML Activity Diagrams to model parallel tasks.  At the end of Chapter 9: Activity Diagrams, the summary says:

> The great strength of activity
>   diagrams lies in the fact that they
>   support and encourage parallel
>   behavior.  This makes them a great
>   tool for workflow modeling and, in
>   principle, for multithreaded
>   programming.